# line of three segments colors html5 css3

Tags: html, image, css, colors, line

I want to create a line divided by three sections (33% each) first  of one color, second of another and a third like the first one. This is used to underline a text, the width should be modified depending on the width of the word.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: it's not easy to understand what you want.. can you povide a picture od design of what you want?

Comment: Check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/).

Comment: I can´t upload images because i`m new, but what I try to explain is to create a line whith diferents segments. Each segment colored.

Comment: -------------------.....................------------------ With great imagination: Imagine it's all one line only. Dots mark a segment of one color and slashes  are other segment with another color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `:after` :pseudo-element with a `linear-gradient`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 88px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<div>This is some text</div>
```

---

To dynamically set the width of the line, you'll have to use JavaScript.

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "div:after") {
      r.style.width = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is some text</span></div>
```

---

If you want solid colors, you'll have to do it using JavaScript.

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "div:after") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth;
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
      r.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right, red, red ' + (w/3) + 'px, green ' + (w/3) + 'px, green ' + (w/3) * 2 + 'px, blue ' + (w/3) * 2 + 'px, blue ' + w + 'px)'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is some text</span></div>
```

Comment: Another question. If I don´t want a gradient. Instead I want hard edges. Is this possible?

Comment: background: linear-gradient(to right, #c4c4c4 30%, #329fb6 30%, #329fb6 70%, #c4c4c4 70%);

Comment: @PabloLevin - Yes I've already added an example. Check out the last snippet.